# Directive that shows a sample depending on what value the user is highlighting

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck with Angular. I have a directive that shows a list and when the user hovers over an item, I want to show a preview of the item, with the preview being given by the directive user.
Some tricks though... I want the user to be able to filter the list using an input [which is easy on it's own] and there is some basic styling surrounding the list that I would like the directive to handle, like adding the checkboxes that well be watched to create the model for the directive.

I want the directive user to simply be able to write:

```
<preview-list list='unfilteredlist'>
    <div>
        <h1><blink>{{title}}</blink></h1>
        <h2><marquee>{{html extrodinaire}}</marquee></h2>
    </div>
</preview-list>
```

I tried using ng-transclude, but it uses a sibling scope and I've been looking for work arounds and I can't find any. The only ones I found involved writing the entire template in javascript, which honestly I can't believe people think that's an acceptable solution.

Any solutions, or is this actually completely impossible in Angular?

Comment: I've tried numerous other ways and work arounds... none of them worked, because of angular's strict scoping.
I'm just going to have to abandon the use of transclusion... I guess the user won't be able to add custom html. :(

Answer (score 0):

As i see it you have two options :

1. Create a preview box for each member in your list and toggle visibility on hover. This is great if you have only a few values and the preview box is heavy.
2. Create a transcluded directive in which - the main scope will hold the list and the currently hover element. The sibling scope will hold the preview container. Once the selected value changes the preview box will update (according to your bindings) and only thing left to do is position it.

transclude is hard at first but it pays off.

Hope this helps.

Comment: option 1 is unfeasible for more than a couple items as you mentioned and option 2 would require the filtering also occur on the main scope, rather than the directive, even though it's the directives code that is doing that filtering; so I wouldn't be able to package the filtering, so for each project that used this directive, they would have to recreate the filtering function or re-attach the function that was included with the directive the module was packaged in.

I know the transclude concept is awesome, but I'm looking for a feasible way I can implement them.

Comment: In the documentation they mention transclude is for arbitrary data, but I'm looking for similar functionality with given data. [ie. from an ng-repeat or a changing scope object]

I'm thinking of maybe creating another directive that can be used to insert arbitrary data in an attribute and it will transclude it, I'm not sure if this is possible... I'll play around tomorrow.

Comment: I could not find a way around it. I tried using a main scope variable as the iterator for the ng-repeat in the directive, but that didn't work. I tried using ng-init to pass the iterator to the main scope variable, but that still didn't work.

I can usually find a way, but Angular has so little options this is appearing impossible.

Thanks for your help, but it looks like I'll just have to abandon transclusion.

I can't wait to ditch Angular for Polymer.